# Do Django filters increases ram consumption per user : Python

Tags: python, django, postgresql, filter, ram

I don't know where else I could have asked this question, thus asking it here. I want to know that if I impose multiple Django filters on a page which are using multiple db tables, will that effect ram consumption whenever a user visits this page because before the user only filtered data will get reflected. I'm using django with postgresql on a ubuntu based VM, also if there are any documentation which can be helpful in understanding ram utilization, please suggest.

Comment: RAM won't be used until your filters are consumed, as filters are lazy. It's the loop that gets the data from those filters. Also, you should not worry about VM's RAM with filters, something else is hogging your data

Comment: This means a filter like this `detail.objects.filter(category_type='Jeans').filter(fit__gte='Tight')[:12]` which is getting used to create a additional category page won't be using any RAM.Am I right?

Comment: Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset. This is from django docs

Comment: And filtering should not affect your RAM consumption

Comment: Thanks.... Please add it as answer so that I can mark it. It might be of help to someone like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django filter and query sets are lazy. What it actually means is you are not actually hitting the database until you **evaluate** them. Quoting official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) -

> Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, sliced, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset.

So the only space that gets taken in your RAM is actually the list containing queryset and your program. It is when query is evaluated and data is extracted from the database, that is when(depending on how much data is extracted), memory is filled. Also, it'd be a good idea to look at [iterators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) as well